# Watch terminal for a particular prompt and automatically enter the response

Tags: command-line, zsh, prompt

I am using ZSH and I am wondering whether there is a way of watching the stdout for a particular prompt and then automatically input the response?

In particular I would like to automatically populate the MFA token when prompted like below;

```
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/jdoe:
```

I can generate the token by the use of the http://soundly.me/oathplus/ tool but want to get this seamlessly working so I don't need to manually enter the token.

Requirements:

I would like to include the script (possibly using expect) in the ~/.zshrc file. This would be loaded once when starting the shell/ terminal and would then be waiting for the prompt "Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/jdoe:". I will then use the terminal in a normal fashion and might eventually use a command that triggers the MFA token prompt.

Note, the MFA token prompt will not always pop up when executing the same command as it depends ono whether the previous connection is still valid. Furthermore, there might be days where I don't use the commands that would trigger the MFA token prompt but this script would still live in the background and jumps into action once there is actually a token prompt. Since the token itself would only be valid for a minute, it needs to be generated after the prompt popped up.

Comment: Sounds like a task for [tag:expect].

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe 'expect' is only useful if you know that you are going to execute the command and expect the prompt. My aim is to use the terminal for whichever commands and it might be days before I execute a command (without explicitly using 'expect') which produces this prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The expect would be something like this:

```
expect -c '
    set mfa_token "your token here"
    set mfa_prompt "Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/jdoe:"
    spawn zsh
    interact {
        -o $prompt {send_user $prompt; send "$mfa_prompt\r"}
    }
'
```

That drops you into zsh, and you interact with it like a normal interactive shell.

The `-o` watches for that prompt coming from the shell's output, and automatically sends the token.

Expect has a pretty narrow use case these days, but this is in the wheelhouse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not quite fit the use case. I will update the question to make it clearer.